# how can I display the item in the third column selected by the user from the dataGridView to the ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a problem displaying the third column selected by the user (binding Source) from the dataGridView to my comboBox in the other Form,

[image]

I tried this code:

```
DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)immobilisation.immobilisationDataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value;
                    String valueOfItem = drv["intitulé_FI"].ToString();
                    comboBox5.Text = valueOfItem;
```

and I get this error:
Impossible to cast an object from 'System.String' to 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

How can I display the item selected in the DataGridView to the comboBox and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is telling you that you can't convert the value of a particular cell (`Cells[2].Value`) to a `DataRowView`. Use this instead:

```
comboBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
```

Or replace `2` with `"intitulé_FI"` if that's your column name.